# GetClientRect on WM_SIZING gives wrong size

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, winapi

I need to get correct size (width / height) of window's client area, when window is being resized. I tried to use `GetClientRect`, but it ALWAYS gives WRONG values (see details below).

```
User32.RECT clientRECT;
User32.GetClientRect(_handle, out clientRECT);
```

So I decided to store x- and y-delta, between window rect (with borders) and client rect, when window is created, and then sum up this delta values with window rect, received from lParam of `WM_SIZING` message.

```
var windowRECT = (User32.RECT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(User32.RECT));
var clientAreaWidth = ((windowRECT.right - windowRECT.left) + _xDelta);
var clientAreaHeight = ((windowRECT.bottom - windowRECT.top) + _yDelta);
```

This trick ALWAYS gives RIGHT size.

But why GetClientRect has such strange behavior? So I wrote this code to get more details about what is going on.

```
Debug.WriteLine("dX: " + (clientRECT.right - clientAreaWidth).ToString() + ", dY: " + (clientRECT.bottom - clientAreaHeight).ToString());
```

Then I started project and began dragging right-bottom corner of the window. Here's the output:

```
dX: 16, dY: 17 // fast dragging in NW-direction
dX: 21, dY: 16
dX: 34, dY: 25
dX: 92, dY: 62
dX: 110, dY: 75
dX: 94, dY: 65
dX: 60, dY: 48
dX: 22, dY: 19
...
dX: 0, dY: 1 // slow dragging in NW-direction
dX: 0, dY: 2
dX: 0, dY: 1
dX: 0, dY: 1
dX: 0, dY: 1
dX: 1, dY: 1
dX: 0, dY: 1
dX: 1, dY: 2
dX: 0, dY: 1
...
dX: -16, dY: -12 // fast dragging in SE-direction
dX: -68, dY: -65
dX: -77, dY: -75
dX: -53, dY: -43
dX: -22, dY: -17
dX: -5, dY: -4
...
dX: -1, dY: 0 // slow dragging in SE-direction
dX: -1, dY: 0
dX: -1, dY: 0
dX: -1, dY: -1
dX: -1, dY: 0
dX: -1, dY: -1
dX: -1, dY: 0
dX: 0, dY: -1
dX: -1, dY: 0
dX: 0, dY: -1
```

What cause this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `WM_SIZING`, you need to use the rect carried in the `lParam`, not the results of `GetClientRect`

Comment: Why? And when the result of GetClientRect function becomes correct?

Comment: You can use GetClientRect when resize is complete (after WM_SIZE)

Comment: May be you wrote some code that interferes with the normal processing of sizing messages. It happenned to me! On http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36700340/revisions you will see I added the call to the parent's method because some drawings of the view depended on the `GetClientRect` function. Those drawings were at the wrong position, but when I added this call, things began to work right!

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer correctly states, you should use the `RECT*` in `lParam` provided by `WM_SIZING` instead of doing extra calls that may return something out of date.

Since it provides the screen rectangle of the window, including the window border size, here's [one way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131017-00/?p=2903) you can retrieve the client rectangle from it:

```cpp
case WM_SIZING:
{
    // Get size of window border.
    // TODO: replace WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW with your window style.
    RECT pad{};
    check_bool(AdjustWindowRect(&pad, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE));

    // Subtract window border from screen rectangle to retrieve client rectangle.
    RECT* screenRect = (RECT*)lParam;
    RECT clientRect
    {
        screenRect->left - pad.left,
        screenRect->top - pad.top,
        screenRect->right - pad.right,
        screenRect->bottom - pad.bottom
    };

    // TODO: Use the client rectangle in your code.
    LONG clientWidth = clientRect.right - clientRect.left;
    LONG clientHeight = clientRect.bottom - clientRect.top;

    break;
}
```